# How can I use :hover with multiple classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got a css buttons style and some predefined colour styles. I use colour classes to colour things the same colour and a button style to make the buttons round.

How do I add a hover style to my buttons to change the colour to a lighter shade? I thought it would be as simple as .class class2:hover {etc} but it doesn't work for some reason.

Here's a fiddle I prepared to demonstrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/7n4Wy/

HTML

```
<p class="red button">Test</p>
<p class="blue button">Test</p>
<p class="red"> Not a button </p>
```

CSS

```
.red {
    background: red;
}

.blue {
    background: blue;    
}

.button {
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.button:hover .red:hover {
    background: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you have is trying to match `.red:hover` that is *inside* `.button:hover`, which implies a nested element in your markup.

Since you're selecting the same element, you need to combine both classes with a single `:hover`:

```
.red.button:hover {
    background: pink;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/7n4Wy/1)

Comment: Ah my bad - I had a space in there.

Comment: @ac7web: :) You could just as easily drop the space so you have `.button:hover.red:hover`, which will work but is confusing because of the doubled `:hover`.

Comment: Yes I originally had .red .button:hover but it didn't work because of the space.

Answer (score 8):

You can apply a CSS-rule to multiple selectors (classes like «.button», or states like «:hover») by separating them with a comma.

therefore just add a comma:

```
.button:hover, .red:hover {
    background: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following code [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7n4Wy/2/)

```
.button.red:hover {
    background: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To apply multiple classes, don't add a space (just use another period):

CSS

```
p.button {
    border-radius: 6px;
}

p.red {
    background: 6px;
}

p.button.red:hover {
    background: pink;
}
```

HTML

```
<p class="button red">Hover Here</p>
```

The space is used to denote a child element. i.e. p.button red:hover would affect all elements with class red on hover that are wholly contained in parent paragraphs with class button.