# Tooltip text not showing after replace()

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to dynamically add elements and classes to html to create tooltips on the fly. Here's my code so far:

```
//index.html
<div id="japanese">ね、 毎日 動画 今日 も 頑張りましょう</div>

//script.js
function findWords() {

  $("#japanese").each(function() {
    let japRegEx = /([\u3040-\u309f]|[\u30a0-\u30ff]|[\uff66-\uff9f]|[\u4e00-\u9faf])+/g

    var $this = $(this);
    // $this.html($this.text().replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
    $this.html(
      $this
        .text()
        .replace(
          japRegEx,
          //"<span>$&</span>"   //This line works
          "<span class=\"tooltip\">$&<span class=\"tooltiptext\">Tooltip text</span></span>" //this line doesn't work
        )
    );
  });
}
findWords();

//style.css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

It seems to work when I'm just adding the span elements, but when I add the classes the text no longer renders (even though it appears in the inspect panel). What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**
When I paste this code into codepen it works ok, but is not working in Glitch?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `hover` with two different classes where one is inside the other. You might find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818107/how-can-i-use-hover-with-multiple-classes

Comment: Thanks. I tried  `.tooltip.tooltiptext:hover` to no avail. These nested classes seem common to tooltips and usually seem to work with this css structure. eg [How to - Tooltip](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp)